# When I run the code, graph axes appear under the table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

# First, we'll create a new figure and axis object

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# Set the number of rows and cols for our table

rows = 10
cols = 6

# Create a coordinate system based on the number of rows/columns

# Adding a bit of padding on bottom (-1), top (1), right (0.5)

ax.set_ylim(-1, rows + 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, cols + .5)
x = datetime.datetime.now()
e = datetime.datetime.now()

# Sample data

data = [
        {'id': 'player10', 'Price %': 125.658, 'Vol %': 255.489, 'goals': 125.859},
        {'id': 'player9', 'Price %': 2, 'Vol %': 72, 'goals': 0},
        {'id': 'player8', 'Price %': 3, 'Vol %': 47, 'goals': 0},
        {'id': 'player7', 'Price %': 4, 'Vol %': 99, 'goals': 0},
        {'id': 'player6', 'Price %': 5, 'Vol %': 84, 'goals': 1},
        {'id': 'player5', 'Price %': 6, 'Vol %': 56, 'goals': 2},
        {'id': 'player4', 'Price %': 7, 'Vol %': 67, 'goals': 0},
        {'id': 'player3', 'Price %': 8, 'Vol %': 91, 'goals': 1},
        {'id': 'player2', 'Price %': 9, 'Vol %': 75, 'goals': 3},
        {'id': 'player1', 'Price %': 10, 'Vol %': 70, 'goals': 4}
]

for row in range(rows):

    d = data[row]

    ax.text(x=.5, y=row, s=d['id'], va='center', ha='left')

    ax.text(x=2.5, y=row, s=d['Price %'], va='center', ha='right')

    ax.text(x=3.5, y=row, s=d['Vol %'], va='center', ha='right')

    ax.text(x=4.5, y=row, s=d['goals'], va='center', ha='right')


ax.text(.5, 9.75, '', weight='bold', ha='left')
ax.text(2.5, 9.75, 'Price %', weight='bold', ha='right')
ax.text(3.5, 9.75, 'Vol %', weight='bold', ha='right')
ax.text(4.5, 9.75, 'Goals', weight='bold', ha='right')

for row in range(rows):
    ax.plot(
        [0, cols + 1],
        [row -.5, row - .5],
        ls=':',
        lw='.5',
        c='grey'
    )

ax.plot([0, cols + 1], [9.5, 9.5], lw='.5', c='black')

ax.set_title(
    " test1                 %s/%s/%s" % (e.day, e.month, e.year),
    loc='left',
    fontsize=15,
    weight='bold',
    color='r'
)
plt.show()
```

When I run the Python code, the chart axes appear under the table. How can I destroy them?

Waiting for the axes not to come out. How can I fix this?

I don't think there is an error anywhere, but I think there is a place where I wrote missing. I have not encountered such a problem in other graphics, but I do not know what the fix will be in this code.

Comment: Your image of a table with data is invisible. But please please please please don't do that. Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74787467/edit) (it covers program input and output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([matplotlib.pyplot.axis, axis -off parameter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html)):

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Gives #

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Gives # "?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74787669/edit) (it covers program input and output as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen I'm aware of this rule [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)..Here expected output is a table in the form of image...OP written code such that code generates tables as output...You are saying I've to apply OCR to output?